# Organization Administration Locked...?

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer-console, error-messages

After having my Developer Console not be able to save a class that I edited, I faced this error message when trying to edit/save the class directly in the browser:

**Organization Administration Locked**

"The changes you requested require salesforce.com to temporarily lock your organization's administration setup. However, the administration setup has already been locked by another change. Please wait for the previous action to finish, then try again later."

Any idea what is causing this and/or what I can do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running large numbers of tests, or deploying code?

Comment: Neither, just trying to save a few classes and a VF page that I was working on in a Developer Org. No test classes were involved at all.

Comment: did you or someone else logged in click run all tests?

Comment: No, this did not happen after even a single test was run

Comment: This happens to me very occasionally for "no reason". In all cases it's resolved itself in under an hour, so I'd copy-paste your code changes and keep trying periodically. 95% of the time I see this message, it's because someone else has hit run all tests or is running a long-running unit test, but I have seen it happen for no apparent reason. Never had it hung for more than a few minutes if it's not run-all-tests-related.

Answer (score 12):

This usually means:

1. Something is being deployed via API (check Setup -> Monitor Deployments)
2. Something is being deployed via changesets (Setup -> Deploy -> Inbound change sets)
3. You're running some unit tests.

Your request (from developer console, Eclipse or whatever) might have been canceled / timed out but the deployment still runs. One of these means should give you a hint what's going on.... You might also check setup aoudit trail if the condition persists.

If your class failed to save but it seems to be still checking - maybe you've modified something "big". Will many visualforce pages / apex clases that rely on this class suddenly become invalid because you deleted a lot? In that case it might be worth a while to help SF dependency checker by commenting out majority of these VF classes before saving your main change...

Comment: I am neither deploying anything or running unit tests. I was just trying to save a few classes and a VF page that I was working on in a Developer Org. No test classes were involved at all. It is possible that the class that I saved affected several other classes that I was not actively working on, however, shouldn't I still be able to save my work?

Comment: Still, can you check these setup areas (especially "monitor deployments"). I've never edited a class from Dev Console but it shouldn't be too different from editing Apex class from web interface - and that can be seen both in "monitor deployments" and debug logs.

Comment: As a side comment, this can also happen if you are working with multiple developers and they save a class at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I checked 'monitor deployments' and it is empty. Additionally, I was not working with multiple developers, but I was trying to save multiple classes within a few seconds of each other (I was working on a few tabs at once in the Dev Console). I also tried resaving a class that froze up the first time, which probably didn't help, but I still don't know why it froze to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

A circular dependency between a Page and Controller will produce your exact symptoms, but I'd raise a case to Salesforce. There are reasonable situations where this may happen inadvertently:

**Jackerman.page**

```
<apex:page controller="JackermanController">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton value="Create new Contact then come back" action="{!doRedirect}" />
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**JackermanController.cls**

```
public class JackermanController {
  public PageReference doRedirect() {
    String retUrl = Page.Jackerman.getUrl();
    return '/003/e?' + retUrl;
  }
}
```

In that example, one could do `new PageReference('/apex/Jackerman').getUrl()` to remove the compile-time dependency from the Apex class... unless your org is locked, that is ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced this.  It has ALWAYS been a situation where dev console doesn't like something about a dependency...crAzy annoying that it won't tell you which one.

Best solution is to open up all the referenced components, composition templates, classes, classes with methods called by those classes, etc.  add a space somewhere and resafe...dev console will fuss about one of them.  Fix that, and you fix the problem.

Note...there likely nothing officially wrong with your code.  The ones I've had would save out of IDE or the develop>classes edit.  It's something specific that dev console doesn't like.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your issue, but I've had instances where a pending deployment got stuck and locked out the org completely.  Usually this resolves itself in a day, but if it doesn't you can contact support to unstick it.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully it's cleared up by tomorrow. I hadn't run any deployment, just tried to save a few classes

Comment: Hope that cleared it up.  Fyi, saving a class is just a single file deployment, so it's not unrealistic that something may have gotten locked up underneath the covers.  Probably goes without saying, but that means if you save a production apex class you'll have to wait until all tests have run until you can make another change, sandbox is just faster since they don't run test.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **Organization Administration Locked** This is mysterious (for unknown reason).

My case that cause of `Apex Compilation Errors`, before knowing this I'm trying to add a new file and sfdc returning me "Organization Administration Locked".

To know what wrong Setup -> Develop -> Apex Classes > 
Compile all classes.
Then the problem will shown and after fix the compilation error, "Organization Administration Locked" is gone.

Comment: How could you save the updated class if the org was locked?

Comment: actually, as mentioned the problem is not from "Organization Administration Locked". and nothing more specify - just in that case my problem was solve by re-compile & fix those error apex classes

Answer (score 0):

Additional case that it can happen- if you lots of classes/trigger and you use the  button 'Compile All', then this process might take few minutes (and you cannot stop it). During this time the organization is locked for changes and you just have to wait few minutes.