# Save error: Unable to perform save on all files

Tags: error

I was working on my force project and out of no where I get the following error:

Save error: Unable to perform save on all files: The changes you requested require salesforce.com to temporarily lock your organization's administration setup. However, the administration setup has already been locked by another change. Please wait for the previous action to finish, then try again later. (ALREADY_IN_PROCESS)
    /master/.git/objects/7a line 1  Force.com save problem

I was working as usual and I'm not sure what I did.  Any suggestion on how to resolve this and why it happened?

THX

Comment: Check out Eyescream's post in the thread I referenced. It should be the answer you are looking for - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8680/605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a random shot, this happens when someone in your org hit the "Run all Test" in the apex class section.Go to setup--> develop --> Apex Test Execution and see if there are tests that is currently running if there is try to see who initiated this and abort it if it was started accidentally. ( If there is no such tests running, then I would refer to the post by Jesse Altman)