# Causes of organization lock

Tags: deployment, migration-tool, locking

I recently tried to deploy some changes between sandboxes using the Force.com migration tool and got the following error:

> Failed to process the request successfully. Cause(ALREADY_IN_PROCESS): null: The changes you requested require salesforce.com to temporarily lock your organization's administration setup. However, the administration setup has already been locked by another change. Please wait for the previous action to finish, then try again later.

According to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8678/organization-administration-locked), the organization can be locked by deployments (of course) or during unit tests (seems odd to me, never seen it before).  Regardless, neither of these is happening in the org I am working in.  Is there documentation somewhere that lists all potential causes of an organization lock?

Comment: This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491229/salesforce-stuck-in-organization-administration-locked-state-after-using-apex-te

Comment: Seems like it could be a release upgrade? Or perhaps one of the many long running re-calculations such as sharing changes, forecasting changes, picklist changes on a large object. I'm sure there are other examples.

Comment: The bad thing is that it doesn't put request into queue (like keeping it in Pending state), but just throws that error and breaks our CI. Why doesn't it just hang in Pending status waiting for org to become unlocked(

Answer (score -3):

[**'Org Administration Locked' error**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004045&type=1) in Salesforce documentation.

Refer to the link for more detailed explanation and potential causes.

Comment: This is Link only answer which is considered as low quality, would you mind adding few bits and bobs?