# Organization Administration Locked

Tags: org, locking

good old message is the following :

> Organization Administration Locked 
>   The changes you requested require salesforce.com to temporarily lock your organization's administration setup. 
>   However, the administration setup has already been locked by another change. Please wait for the previous action to finish, then try again later.

I tried everything described in [Organization Administration Locked...?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8678/organization-administration-locked/8680#8680)

- There is no current deployment:
  [image]
- This is no current Unit Test
  [image]
- Click on dev console "cancel all deployments"
  [image]
- Create/delete/switch workspaces: unsuccessful
- Is there a way (script ? setup menu?)  to know WHICH current lock is blocking us ?

Comment: You can check the "Setup Audit Trail" to view recent actions that may be preventing you from further changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Open an existing class in the Developer Console
- Go to File and click Save (even without changes)

Else you can try to save the class with the Metadata API instead of the Tooling API in a tool like the Force.com IDE or MavensMate

There's a known issue with this, but a colleague of mine fixed it with the above steps.
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000E1YYQA0

Comment: Also not working from Force.com IDE :/ There is something locking but no way to fidn what, and this lasts since nearly 4 hours now ... we are 5 devs to be stucked because of that :/

Comment: And you used the Metadata API with the IDE?

Comment: Yes, as Force.Com default settings use Metadata API

Comment: Tryin with Tooling API didn't help either :/